# Adding new website for Experience Manager previewing with session

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

At that moment we have already configured and working properly Experience Manager previewing with session ability (for desktop content).
Recently, we've been asked to add one more website (mobile content previewing) with ability to preview content under the current user session.
New preview works fine for already published content, but we have problem to make it show the content from the current user session.
We added new website url in the previewing target and restarted IIS, but we still get only published content for new website url.
Are there something else must to be configured for new previewing urls to enable session preview functionality?